# Ansible update user password

Tags: ansible

```
ansible 192.168.1.115 -s -m shell -a "echo -e 'oldpassword\nnewpassword\nnewpassword' | passwd myuser" -u myuser --ask-sudo-pass
```

I would like to update existing user with new password, I had tried this command, but it doesn't work

appreciate any Tips !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can leverage the `user` module to quickly change the password for desired account. Ansible doesn’t allow you to pass a cleartext password to user module so you have to install a password hashing library to be leveraged by Python.

To install the library:

```
sudo -H pip install passlib
```

Then simply exexute your command:

```
ansible 192.168.1.115 -s -m user -a "name=root update_password=always password={{ yourpassword | password_hash('sha512') }}" -u myuser --ask-sudo-pass
```

Hope that help you

Comment: Thank you, i had tried once more,  it's working perfectly

Comment: `password_hash('sha512')` is almost perfect except it always leave 'user' task in the 'changed' state.

Comment: If password is `int` or `float` you need `password={{ yourpassword | string | password_hash('sha512') }}"` i guess.

Answer (score 4):

Create your shadow password (linux) with

```
python -c 'import crypt; print crypt.crypt("YourPassword", "$6$random_salt")'
```

create 
[update_pass.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8eSV.png)

execute your ansible-playbook with sudoer (bash)

```
ansible-playbook update_pass.yml --become --become-method='sudo' --ask-become-pass
```

Comment: also share what you have in your `update_pass.yml` file for reference for others.

Comment: For a SHA-512 hash with auto random salt: python3 -c 'import crypt; print(crypt.crypt("test", crypt.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512)))' - [from related ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/330069/how-to-create-an-sha-512-hashed-password-for-shadow/330072#330072)

Answer (score 2):

Update password for a list of hosts using dynamic variables:

In your inventory file set a variable (pass) as the following:

```
 ip_1@ ansible_user=xxxxxx ansible_ssh_pass=xxxx ansible_sudo_pass=xxx pass='aaaa'
 ip_2@ ansible_user=xxxxxx ansible_ssh_pass=xxxx ansible_sudo_pass=xxx pass='bbbb'
```

Now in the playbook we make a backup of the shadow file and set cron task to restore the shadow file in case something went wrong than we update the password:

```
- hosts: your_hosts
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: backup shadow file
      copy:
        src: /etc/shadow
        dest: /etc/shadaw.org
      become: yes

    - name: set cron for backup
      cron:
        name: restore shadow
        hour: 'AT LEAST GIVE YOURSELF ONE HOUR TO BE ABLE TO CALL THIS OFF'
        minute: *
        job: "yes | cp /tmp/shadow /etc/"
      become: yes

    - name: generate hash pass
      delegate_to: localhost
      command:  python -c "from passlib.hash import sha512_crypt; import getpass; print sha512_crypt.encrypt('{{pass}}')"
      register: hash


    - debug:
        var: hash.stdout

    - name: update password
      user:
        name: xxxxxx
        password:  '{{hash.stdout}}'
      become: yes
```

Now we create a new playbook to call off cron task we use the new password for authentication and if authentication failed cron will remain active and restore the old password.

hosts file:

```
   ip_1@   ansible_user=xxxxxx ansible_ssh_pass=aaaa ansible_sudo_pass=aaaa
   ip_2@   ansible_user=xxxxxx ansible_ssh_pass=bbbb ansible_sudo_pass=bbbb
```

the playbook:

```
- hosts: your_hosts
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:

    - name: cancel cron task
      cron:
        name: restore shadow
        state: absent
```

**!!Remember:**

- **pass** variable contain your password so you may consider using vault.
- Give yourself time when setting cron for backup to be able to call it of (second playbook).
- In worst case cron will restore the original password.
- You need to have passlib installed in your ansible server.